# Gaussian process for signal registration

Tags: gaussian-process

Suppose we want to align two 1D signals X and Y. We model the residuals between the signals as a Gaussian Process:

$$
Y = X + B + \epsilon
$$

Where $B$ is smooth noise and $\epsilon$ is independent white noise. One way to write the Gaussian Process likelihood is:

$$
Y-X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,K+\epsilon)
$$

Since the task is alignment, one would move Y and/or X until the likelihood is maximized. However, my issue is with practicality. When Y and X aren't close together, the difference signal $Y-X$ is very far from zero, and therefore the likelihood will be extremely low. In fact, the "difference signal" could remain very non-zero until the signals are perfectly aligned! Thus this GP might not be terribly useful if the signals are too difficult to align (a bigger problem in higher dimensions).

My question is, is there another metric that one could model as a GP that would give better performance as Y approaches X?